# How to change to a directory using an environment variable in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory

I try to create a small application that uses the default Microsoft sorting feature to sort out my folders. I use a variable called `tosort` which upon user entry is supposed to check if the directory exists.

Here is my code:

```
echo off
:retry
set /p tosort=Enter the Directory to sort :
chdir "tosort"
if exist %tosort%\ (
    echo "DIRECTORY FOUND"
    )else (
    goto :retry)
```

However, whenever batch processing reaches `%tosort%\` there is output the error message:

> c:\ was not expected

Comment: What is the expected input from the user?  A fully qualified path or a relative path? If you want to do a change directory you have to use the actual variable with percent symbols like you are doing with the `IF` command.

Comment: as already stated by @Squashman , you have to use `%tosort%` and not `tosort`, but also instead use `cd /d "%tosort%"` and I am failing to see why you want to `cd` first and then check if exist, rather check existance, then `cd` to it.

Comment: There are of course many ways of achieving something, contrary to the suggestion above, I'd `ChDir`/`PushD` to `"%tosort%"`, and its success or otheriwse would determine its existence status, _(no need for an `If Exist`)_.

Comment: @Compo It's certainly more a matter of preference, but FWIW IF EXIST works natively on UNC Paths and to different drive letters, and doesn't actually change the execution location, which ultimately might be needed in some step before the change to that directory location, or (as I generally prefer) CD may be avoided entirely (as changing paths is more work than checking, and often unnecessary for the script to be run efficiently.) Granted I left the `Chdir` in for now and just fixed it to use the `%` around the variable, I figured one thing at a time, but it's a fair point Mofi makes about UNC

Comment: @Compo As may be completely a matter of my perception, and not reality, I often Find `PushD` and `PopD` to be slow in accessing UNC paths, and attribute this to the drive mapping, which also is generally a reason I can't use these myself as I'm used to Windows systems having no or few spare allotments for drives, which breaks `PushD` and `PopD` especially if you have a sequence where you might open a few places, and may forget to `PopD` effectively as it's on you to properly garbage collect your `PushD` drive mappings as you execute your script

Comment: I would guess @BenPersonick, that because `PushD` not only creates a temporary mapping, but adds to the stack, that it will take a little longer to perform that than a straight `ChDir` command. However, I doubt that speed reduction would be detrimental to using label `Call`s, creating a variable, checking its last character with an `If Exist`, adjusting if necessary, then performing another `If Exist` on that. Like I said, there are many ways of performing a task, and each has their own preferences, it just happens that my first instinct matches the example in the answer by Mofi.

Comment: @Compo I also said this is a matter of preference, and didn't mean to imply you said any differently, you definitely said that there was more than one way to skin a cat, and I was attempting to validate that by agreeing it's a matter of preference.  I actually tried to indicate that I DO NOT prefer to `Chdir` at all, and instead prefer to use UNC paths stored in variables and feed those to the commands I need to do, unless absolutely necessary to change the working path. In which case if working with UNC I usually prefer to `MKLINK` to a folder I control. FWIW that could be used for local too.

Comment: @Compo In the world of SSDs and SANs Label calls are still a (smaller) concern, but I have seen drive mappings take seconds under PushD and PopD depending on what I am connecting to, and how many files are on the remote path, and that system's own abilities, as windows seems to do some additional things under the hood when mapping a drive and changing to it which I assume may include some basic requests related to that info as it seems to make a difference in the speed of the process.  I've also run into Systemerror67 when mapping/unmapping drives repeatedly, which doesn't seem to affect UNCs.

Comment: I have not had such issues @BenPersonick, so would not expect them to be common occurrences. I would also would not assume the type of drive the OP is using, or the capabilities of their system software or hardware. Based upon the question code provided, I'm not even sure that the OP is expecting a typed full path as input, with the likelihood being they're just expecting a relative directory name. Of course if it's relative, then its even less likely that UNC paths would be a significant issue, as the current directory will already be available and defined. Also their error shows as `C:\ `

Comment: @Compo I'm used to having to do quite a lot in the datacenter and working with very large sets of data and also having to hit ancient machines along with the good ones from file shares I have a lot of direct experience with what can go wrong and cause issues, and how to optimize to avoid them At least NT4 onward.  Label calls are 'slow' but even since NT5 the GMMF has means that windows only checks if the file is modified and then uses the memory mapped copy, even if that weren't he case, this is why we have caches on hard disks that were into the mulit-MB by the mid 2000s. Its negligible.

Answer (score 2):

Your code may simply be failing because you have spaces in the directory path, if there are spaces in a path you need to use double quotes around it. `"%tosort%\"`

I have refactored tour code a bit to be more readable and utilize functions, including a main function.

By using `Call :Label` we move to the function label, and return and execute the next line when the function completes.

This means rhe end of the script is the `Endlocal` potion.

Its a good practice to use `SetLocal` and `endlocal` in your scripts so that if you call one from another the changes generated in one do not exist in the other.  (If you have some variables you want to return you can place them within the parenthesis block before the exit /b)

Functions are best ended with `GOTO :EOF`, the `:EOF` label is a place holder for the end of the file, as a script or function is read until the end of the file.  A function at the end of the file could leave this off, but better to leave it on and have all your functions uniformly declared.

Edit: Since you probably want to check if the directory exists with a trailing `\` and then later use it without the trailing `\` for some other commands, and since a user may add the trailing `\` themselves, and may wrap the path in double quotes `"` themselves I am amending this to do the checking for all that.

Note that `REM` is a remark command use for commenting scripts.

if you change `ECHO OFF` at the top of the script to `ECHO ON` the Remarks will print along with the commands that are being run and you'll be able to see where the script is in it's execution.

```cmd
@(SETLOCAL
  echo off
)

Call :Main

( Endlocal
  Exit /b
)

:Main
  REM Call the SetCheckDir Function
   Call :SetCheckDir

 REM Change directory to the path that we found
  chdir "%tosort%"

REM This following line ends the Main Function
Goto :EOF

:SetCheckDir

  REM Check for the path from the user
   SET /p "tosort=Enter the Directory to sort: "

  REM Clear off double qoutes
   SET "TmpVar=%tosort:"=%"

  REM Add Trailing backslash
   IF /I "%TmpVar:~-1%" NEQ "\" SET "TmpVar=%TmpVar%\"

  REM Test if the Directory path is good:
   IF NOT EXIST "%TmpVar%" ( GOTO :SetCheckDir )

  REM Set the original variable to the found path, minus the trailing backslash
   SET "tosort=%TmpVar:~0,-1%"
Goto :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in code posted in the question:

1. The user can input no string at all in which case the environment variable `tosort` is still not defined or is still defined with the value defined outside of the batch file.
2. The command `chdir "tosort"` does not reference the value of the environment variable which would require the usage of `chdir "%tosort%"`.
3. The usage of `chdir "%tosort%"` would fail to change the current directory if it is on a different drive. The usage of `chdir /D "%tosort%"` would solve this problem.
4. `chdir /D "%tosort%"` would fail if the user of the batch file enters a [UNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Universal_Naming_Convention) path. The solution would be `pushd "%tosort%"` with command extensions enabled and a matching `popd` if the execution of this command was successful which pushes the current directory path on stack and sets the specified folder path as current directory if the folder referenced with `"%tosort%"` exists at all.
5. The user of the batch file could enter a string with one or more `"` in which case all the commands mentioned above would fail to execute correct.
6. `if exist %tosort%\` fails on entered string containing a space or one of these characters `&()^=;!+,~<>|` as the referenced string value is not enclosed in double quotes on execution of this command line.

The solution for all potential problems is using following **commented** code:

```
@echo off
rem Define together with the line above the execution environment completely.
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

:Retry
set "FolderToSort="
set /P "FolderToSort=Enter the directory to sort: "
rem Has the user not input any string at all?
if not defined FolderToSort goto Retry
rem Remove all double quotes from the input string.
set "FolderToSort=%FolderToSort:"=%"
rem Has the user input just double quotes?
if not defined FolderToSort goto Retry

rem Make the directory entered by the user the current directory.
rem The command PUSHD exits with 0 on success and with 1 on failure.
pushd "%FolderToSort%" 2>nul
echo(
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo ERROR: There is no accessible directory:
    echo        "%FolderToSort%"
    echo(
    goto Retry
)
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Current directory: !CD!
endlocal
echo(

rem Do something in current directory being the directory entered by the user.
dir

rem Restore the initial current directory.
popd
rem Restore the initial execution environment.
endlocal
```

The remarks (comments) can be removed for more efficiency which means all lines beginning with command `rem`.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`